# Array is empty after pushing items (synchronous)

Tags: node.js

I am trying to read file from a .txt file in nodejs, when i get access to each line, I push it to an array but in the end, the array is empty.

```
var array=[];

  let lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: require('fs').createReadStream('file.txt')
  });
  
  lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
    console.log(line);
    array.push(line);
  });

console.log(array);
```

**.Txt File Content**

```
THIS IS LINE#1
THIS IS LINE#2
THIS IS LINE#3
```

**Output**

```
[]
THIS IS LINE#1
THIS IS LINE#2
THIS IS LINE#3
```

Comment: `lineReader.on('line',  function (line) {...})` is not synchronous ( mean, the function you pass to it is not called synchronously).

Comment: You say it's synchronous in the title...but an event listener (= `on(...)`) is not synchronous (as you can see in the output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the thing happens async. You need to add a listener for `close` event.

```
lineReader.on("close", () => {
    console.log(array);
})
```